# pandas: Behaviour of label-location based indexer (loc) with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I just started using pandas a couple of days ago, and I'm not a habitual user of Python either. I'm finding the following behaviour of `loc` in the example shown below perplexing:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-01-07')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sunnyland':[34, 36, 32, 37, 34, 36, 38], 'Freezeville':[4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 2]}, index=dates)
```

creates the dateframe:

[Excuse the formatting issue with the column names, they ought to be aligned with the table columns]:

> ```
> Freezeville   Sunnyland
> 2015-01-01    4   34
> 2015-01-02    5   36
> 2015-01-03    6   32
> 2015-01-04    5   37
> 2015-01-05    5   34
> 2015-01-06    3   36
> 2015-01-07    2   38
> ```

Now let's use `loc` to select rows:

```
df.loc['2015-01-02'] # select single row
```

This works as expected, outputting a `Series` object:

> ```
> Freezeville     5
> Sunnyland      36
> Name: 2015-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: int64
> ```

The following works fine too

```
df.loc['2015-01-02':'2015-01-06'] # select range of rows:
```

Outputting:

> ```
> Freezeville   Sunnyland
> 2015-01-02    5   36
> 2015-01-03    6   32
> 2015-01-04    5   37
> 2015-01-05    5   34
> 2015-01-06    3   36
> ```

The problem is with the following statement:

```
df.loc[['2015-01-02', '2015-01-06']] # comma-separated list of rows
```

which produces

> ```
>   Freezeville     Sunnyland
> 2015-01-02    NaN     NaN
> 2015-01-06    NaN     NaN
> ```

I would've thought there was some sort of type inference problem occuring here - except that in that case I would expect a `KeyError` or something, rather than the result seen.

So what's the explanation, and how can I select multiple (arbitrary) rows by date?

Comment: I think you should use `df.loc[['2015-01-02', '2015-01-06'], :] ` to get what you want. Also might need to use tuple instead of list

Comment: @YannisP. That throws an error: `KeyError: "[['2015-01-02', '2015-01-06']] are not in ALL in the [index]`. And with a tuple, i.e. `df.loc[('2015-01-02', '2015-01-03'), :]` I get the same behaviour I got with my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the explanation, maybe the current implementation is hard to generalize to list indexing. It will work if you use actual timestamps instead of strings:

```
In [31]: df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-02', '2015-01-06'])]
Out[31]: 
            Freezeville  Sunnyland
2015-01-02            5         36
2015-01-06            3         36
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need convert string to `datetime` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and get [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), because you need match index:

```
print pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02')
2015-01-02 00:00:00

print pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02').date()
2015-01-02

print df.loc[[pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02').date(), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-06').date()]] 
            Freezeville  Sunnyland
2015-01-02            5         36
2015-01-06            3         36
```